# Reference to an alias component in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm facing a problem in **Ionic 2**. I would to push a new view by getting a **reference/alias** to the component page.

On my parent class (SettingsPage), I try to push a new page :

```
<ion-item [navPush]="addon.settingsLandingClss">
    {{ addon.name }}
    <ion-icon name="arrow-forward" item-right></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

Parent class (SettingsPage) TypeScript :

```
import * as Mapping from '[...]';

export class SettingsPage {
     public addon: Mapping.AddonMapModel;
     constructor() {
          this.addon = Mapping.AddonMap;
     }
}
```

I'm storing the page component as 'settingsLandingClss' key:

```
// Importing page component
import { MyComponentPage }  from '...';

export interface AddonMapModel {
    name: string,
    settingsLandingClss: any
}

export const AddonMap = { 
     name: 'Test', 
     settingsLandingClss: MyComponentPage // <--- Reference to component page
 }
```

Note: When I import MyComponentPage on my parent class, it's works.

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: Push is not working (addon.settingsLandingClss is undefined).

Comment: I'm also trying to instance MyComponentPage by his name class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue by instantiating **MyComponentPage** by its name.

Here is an example (SettingsPage) :

```
import * as SettingsLandingPages from '[...]';

addon.settingsLandingClss = SettingsLandingPages['nameofclass'];
```

And for SettingsLandingPages :

```
// Exporting all landing settings page

export * from './mycomponent.page';
```

For more info and example :[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/B3kT529ONBvhJu5yuW6W)

Thx all !